# ML classification model for any pic input size

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I'm learning for weeks now how to train own models to classify images.

So far I trained some models and got a rough overview about classification.

The training pictures for my model are 3x32x32, training works fine. Predictions with test images works also fine, as long as they come in the same dimensions as the training pics.
I already added adaptive max pooling before fully connected layers, any image size can also be used with the model but the predictions are always wrong.

Can anyone tell me why it behaves like this and how can I improve it?

Thats may model:

```
class ResNet9(ImageClassificationBase):
def __init__(self, in_channels, num_classes):
    super().__init__()

    self.conv1 = conv_block(in_channels, 64)
    self.conv2 = conv_block(64, 128, pool=True)
    self.res1 = nn.Sequential(conv_block(128, 128), conv_block(128, 128))

    self.conv3 = conv_block(128, 256, pool=True)
    self.conv4 = conv_block(256, 512, pool=True)
    self.res2 = nn.Sequential(conv_block(512, 512), conv_block(512, 512))

    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d(1),
                                  nn.Flatten(),
                                  nn.Dropout(0.2),
                                  nn.Linear(512, num_classes))

  
def forward(self, xb):
    out = self.conv1(xb)
    out = self.conv2(out)
    out = self.res1(out) + out
    out = self.conv3(out)
    out = self.conv4(out)
    out = self.res2(out) + out
    out = self.classifier(out)
    return out
```

Normalization part:

```
# create dataset
stats = ((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010))
train_trans = tt.Compose(
    [tt.RandomCrop(32, padding=4, padding_mode='reflect'),
     tt.ToTensor(),
     tt.Normalize(*stats, inplace=True)])
test_trans = tt.Compose([tt.ToTensor(),
             tt.Normalize(*stats, inplace=True)])
```

Comment: Does this model (the version you provided here) able to learn on your train dataset and does it perform well on your validation set. Are you normalizing your inputs? What kind of 
 image preprocessing are you applying?

Comment: I train the model to over 98% accuracy and the train pics are hand written Russian letters. I normalize the input but the result is the same also without normalization.

Comment: Have you normalized your test data with your trainset's mean and std?

Comment: I normalize like in the answer below.

Comment: Have you tried cropping the test set as well so your inputs have the same dimensions as during training. You could try with `torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop` (for the test set) instead of a random crop. [Please avoid creating an answer (you can if it actually provides one), instead edit your original post, thank you!]

Comment: Well finally the model should be used to search for screenshot images on my picture folder, those images come for example in dimensions like 3x602 x1304 and the letter can be at any place in the pic. When I start to crop such a pic from center to 32x32, then a lot of informations is lost. For a test, I took a small part out of such an image via GIMP and send it through the model, if the dimensions are right, then it sees the right letter. If the picture is a little bigger, then it even works with nn.Resize(32), but this is not useful for big images.